# Verb classification of honorific/humble verbs

Tags: verbs

These verbs:

- [いらっしゃる](http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/leaf/jn2/15386/m0u/%E3%81%84%E3%82%89%E3%81%A3%E3%81%97%E3%82%83%E3%82%8B/)
- [おっしゃる](http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/leaf/jn2/31697/m0u/%E3%81%8A%E3%81%A3%E3%81%97%E3%82%83%E3%82%8B/)
- [くださる](http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/leaf/jn2/61762/m0u/%E3%81%8F%E3%81%A0%E3%81%95%E3%82%8B/)
- [なさる](http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/leaf/jn2/163920/m0u/%E3%81%AA%E3%81%95%E3%82%8B/)
- More?

Are all listed as 五段 verbs, but they don't follow the usual conjugation rules for them.
For example:

- 命令形: いらっしゃる -> いらっしゃい, not いらっしゃれ
- 連用形: Same as above, not いらっしゃり

Is there a separate name/classification for these types of verbs? Such as カ変 for 来る and サ変 for する.

Comment: And ござる, today in the form ございます.

Comment: Related: [Origin of -aru verbs: いらっしゃる、おっしゃる、くださる、なさる](http://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/11465)

Comment: It also bears noting that expected regular forms such as いらっしゃります or くださります did exist.  C.f. 「一升ざけを **下さります** 」 from the [*Tōkaidōchū Hizakurige*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/T%C5%8Dkaid%C5%8Dch%C5%AB_Hizakurige), written in the early 1800s, or 「どなたもよふ **いらっしゃりました** 。きつひ御見かぎりで **ござります** 」 from the *Kakutsū Yūshi* by [Utagawa Kunimasa](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Utagawa_Kunimasa), published in 1797.  I suspect the modern forms arose as a kind of contraction or erosion common in oft-used words, such that the interstitial /-r-/ dropped out of the stem forms for the 連用形 and the 命令形.

Comment: My guess is that these are remnants of western dialect in the standard language from when the power shifted from West to East, similar to ありがとう,おはよう,ようこそ etc. instead of ありがたく,おはやく,よくこそ. But others probably know the details better than I do.

Comment: I haven't found an explanation for why /r/ is elided only in those five verbs and only in certain constructions (e.g. with ます).  Martin 1975 does note that the /r/ is retained in certain other constructions (see p.347).

Comment: @dainichi, that's an interesting idea. However, I find -ります forms from the late 1700s, early 1800s, well after political and cultural influence had moved from Kansai to Kantō.

Comment: @EiríkrÚtlendi, after googling some more, I'm losing faith in my own theory... however, not sure what your point is? It's possible that the regular Eastern form was in competition with the established Western form, and eventually lost, no?

Comment: @dainichi, perhaps, but that assumes that an Eastern form existed. For instance, Shogakukan states that ござある didn't become ござる until the Muromachi, and the ます conjugation didn't happen until the Edo period: 『 **ござる**: 「ござある」の変化。室町時代に起こり、敬語としては敬意の度合いがきわめて高かったが、近世前期には「ます」「まする」を伴う形が生じ、近世後期は「ござります」「ございます」の使用の方が普通となった』 So it sounds like neither -ります nor -います existed for ござる until the Edo period.  Is there a similar but older -ります > -います shift for other verbs in the Kansai that could have served as prototype for this apparent Kantō innovation?  We're still left wondering tho, why just these 5 verbs?

Comment: @EiríkrÚtlendi, as I said I've lost faith in my theory, but my train of thinking was that it was these 5 verbs, exactly because they are used for 敬語. When the power shifted, the Eastern language was "unrefined" and lacked honorific speak, so it's natural that 敬語 expressions were imported from Western dialects (just like the よろしゅう-renyokei still used in よろしゅうございます). Now, as you say, ます is a later innovation, so that is a good counterargument to my theory. So it would be interesting to know whether ござい etc. were used as renyokei in any other contexts.

Comment: @dainichi, aha, your "unrefined" explanation casts your earlier comments into a clearer light, thank you for that.  I too would be most interested to hear of any other /-r-/ elision patterns in other verbs and dialects.

Answer (score 2):

I'd like to point out that those verbs also have "regular" forms of 連体形 and 命令形 even though not used quite often. As an extreme example, when making up the expression 連用中止法, they must be conjugated regularly to 連用形.

> 本日はご来場くださり、誠にありがとうございます。 "Thank you very much for coming today."

but 「本日はご来場ください、誠にありがとうございます」 makes no sense.

Therefore, people tend to think those verbs aren't very different from regular 五段 verbs, and try to account for their irregular forms by phonetic change (both forms) or sometimes by suppletion (only 命令形).

Phonetic change (reduction of R): kudasari > kudasai, kudasare > kudasae > kudasai

Suppletion: in this idea, ください is seen as short for the imperative expression くださいませ, which is a combination of the verb くださる in irregular 連用形 and the auxiliary verb ます in 命令形.

Answer (score -1):

dainichi's comment in the OP is right.

These are left-overs of western dialect that are actually still used today:

**Wants** たい　ー＞　とう　(usually in the negative)

- 行きたくないな・行きとうないな or 行きとうなかね

**て／た forms of 「う」verbs**

- 何買ったの？・なんこうたと？

**General Phonetic Shift** ら行 sounds to い

- それ何？・そいなん？
- その人誰？・そん人だいね？
- 二人は？・ふたいは？

**Scolding**

- 早く行きなさいよ！・はよう行きんしゃい！

With these it's easy to see how ありがとう and いらっしゃい came about.

Comment: It could help to explain a little further: as I understand it, ありがとう is from ありがたく.  When the /k/ was lost, that gave ありがたう, and the regular sound change from /au/ to /oː/ resulted in ありがとう.  So とう is not directly from たい.